# What is necessary to make a disk as clean of (header) info as when it came from the factory?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

Was installing Windows on a new disk (disk0) and noticed some weird behavior:

It asked to and made a new partition on the free disk space I had in the beggining of another disk (disk1), and it wrote some stuff for system/boot purposes there.

The thing I suspect is. That free space in the beggining of disk1 had a partition with Windows installed before I deleted it and it became free space.

So, I'm guessing the installer found something in the header of disk1, and it thought it should write its boot loader there?

I don't really wanna know all the workings for this, but it would be nice to be able to clean your disks headers before you format and end up finding these nasty surprises.

edit: I'm sorry if I gave the impression that I wanted to put everything back to zeros. That's not what I meant. I want to make sure any structure is gone, not the contents. I'm thinking writing a new MBR with a tool like Testdisk will be enough, but am not sure.

Comment: What exactly is the strange behavior?  Windows normally does what you describe when you present it a disk without a filesystem and tell it you want to install it to that disk.

Comment: 1) No it's not. I've seen it install without making extra partitions.
2) In this case, it's installing the extra partition in another hard disk.
3) I'm not really interested in the whys and hows of this behavior. Preventing it will be fine. I know I can try to use Testdisk and rewrite a new MBR.

Comment: Sounds like you already know how to clan your disk headers.  Like I indicate its not clear what the strange behavior is.  What is more likely is disk0 isn't actually disk0.

Comment: Figured it out. Windows 8 will read (somehow) from the bios startup what is your boot-from drive and (at least if it can), will write a boot partiton to that. This happens when you try to install it on another disk, that is not the boot-from drive. This is probably a noob-proof for people with two disk drives that I wasn't aware. Probably not related to disk header info after all.

Comment: @Ramhound it was disk0 in the motherboard too at some point in my experiments, just not the boot-from disk. But I'm confused now. You got a reference for this?

Comment: you can boot the pc with a [clonezilla disk](http://clonezilla.org/) and delete the partions with it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a tool like GParted to write a new partition table, either MBR (for older devices) or GPT for newer ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to completely erase an HDD you need to use some software to write zeros on the whole drive. The quick format that is often used simply removes the file table but the actual information is still written to the HDD. The Full format will just add a scan for bad sectors on top of that. You can use windows diskpart “clean all” to write zeros to the whole drive http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/52129-disk-clean-clean-all-diskpart-command.html.
However that does take a lot of time to finish. Instead you can just unplug the other HDDs when you are installing Windows.

Comment: please read the edit, sorry again